# Python adding unwanted double quotes to a dictionary

Tags: python

After passing a string into a function, Python is generating additional double quotes. For example:

```
def main():
   ...
   foo("string1", "'string2','string3'")
   ...
def foo(var1, var2):
   dictionary = {
      'a' : var1,
      'b' : [var2]
   }
   print(dictionary)
```

I need var2 to be in square brackets for what comes next. The following is the output:

```
{'a': 'string1', 'b': ["'string2','string3'"]}
```

How can the additional double quotes be removed so that `'b': ['string2','string3']`?

Comment: Your passing `"'string2','string3'"` It will be considered as one string, that's the reason  your getting it this way.

Comment: It didn't add anything. Look at your original data.

Comment: You do know **_you_** had double quotes in your original data, right?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 string1 passed without the double quotes, string2 and 3 did not.

Comment: @JaiminAjmeri how can I pass the string so that the double quotes aren't carried?

Comment: The double quotes for `'string1'` (notice how I used single quotes there?) are just there to enclose it, and Python will use single quotes by default when possible. The other object is one string, because you made it so.

Comment: Please, please, ___please___ read a tutorial (like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
'b' : [x[1:-1] for x in var2.split(",")]
```

`split` separates the substrings, and `[1:-1]` removes the quotes.

Comment: Same problem as the other answer. The actual issue is that the OP doesn't understand strings.

Comment: Worked like magic! That's exactly what I needed; thanks.

Comment: @macmoonshine Furthermore, questions such as these shouldn't be answered. It is clear that the OP need a tutorial on string literals in Python, not a "quick fix" solution. I suggest reading over the meta post [Should we be teaching people to think for themsevles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338492/should-we-be-teaching-people-to-think-for-themselves?cb=1)

Comment: @jscionti - It is not what you needed. What you need is to understand how strings are represented. You passed it that in the first place.

Comment: @leaf I haven't heard about string literals and if that's what's causing the issue I'll look into it and learn. Instead of saying "don't answer" isn't it better to provide a solution and add a point in a direction of learning?

Comment: @jscionti - Yes, and the solution _is_ to point in a direction of learning, which has been done. Delivering a "magic" line of code to you that you don't understand isn't a solution.

Comment: Not really. What @TigerhawkT3 and I are trying to convey to you, is that while this may fix your problem _now_, your going to encounter more problems in the future. Reading and learning from a good tutorial on string literals(or strings) in Python, will enable you to debug programs yourself.

Comment: @jscionti - It's like someone saying "I'm doing `3000 + 2000` and getting 5000 instead of 5. How can I fix this?" The correct solution isn't to divide by 1000; it's to learn about place value.